# Android Multi Project Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Why downvotes? My Question is clear...

i have a Project with this Strukture

- App

  - AppModule (Calculator)
  - Module 2 (Weather)
  - Module 3 (Map)

So, the Module2 is a Weather-Aplication, the Module3 is a Map-Application.
my Project runs witout Module3 very well. But when i import Module3, the App crashed by clicking (activate) modul2 with the following error:

```
 07-21 12:41:30.533 8656-8656/bakteriusdeveloper.master I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.cs.android.weminder.MainActivity>
 07-21 12:41:30.534 8656-8656/bakteriusdeveloper.master D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 07-21 12:41:30.538 8656-8656/bakteriusdeveloper.master E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: bakteriusdeveloper.master, PID: 8656
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

In the **Modul2 - Weather** i need to use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

In the **Module3 - Map** i need to use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
```

My questions are:

1. Could the different dependencies be the cause for my problem?
2. If yes, how can i handle this?
3. Should i manage the different dependencies is the project gradle?

This is my App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "bakteriusdeveloper.master"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
}
```

Comment: if you used compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1' in Module 2 then you get crash?

Comment: Yes. But strange, my application with the Version 6.1.71 crashed by button click.

Answer (score 1):

first of all why you have build your module 2 with such old Play Services? like this is not stand of the art u silly sausage.

Second:
different dependencies are ur Problem:
try using this code in ur main method:

```
defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 14java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
     truemultiDexEnabled *#*#3264#*#*}
         stmt.close();
         con.close();
       }
       catch (Exception f){}

       if(loginNameAusDB.equals(loginname)&&loginPWAusDB.equals(loginpassname)){

         jp_center.removeAll();
       }
   }
```

im pleased to help u with all my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Update your gradle file using this code.

```
defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
```

Comment: write multiDexEnabled true in your gradle.

Comment: Yes of course. I will try your tipp. One minute. I have to rebuild my project (import module 3)...

Comment: Sorry, App crashed... Update the logcat message!

Comment: The Modules runs perfectly standalone. But together i get this error! Any Ideas?

Comment: Is there anyone, who can help me? I despair! Dont want to stop my project :-(