# Different Google Play Services in Modules

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

there is a thread from me regarding this topic, but with detailed content.
I am not sure about my error, so here is my Basic-Question:

**Is it possible to use different Google Play Services in modules?**

Project-Structure:

- App

  - AppModule
  - Module 2 Goolge Play Service 6.1.71
  - Module 3 (Map)  Play Service 9.2.1

Comment: For understanding: This is my problem in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500860/android-multi-project-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-execute

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue recently. I was using the following modules of `Google Play Services` with version 9.0.2

1) adds

2) analytics

3) appindexing

4) auth

However, I needed to add a dependency for a new feature in my app.

```
'compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.5.2'
```

The above library had a dependency on version `10.0.1` of `Gcm` module of `Google Play Services`. My gradle sync was successful in Android Studio, but when I tried to build the apk, I got the following error.

```
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForLoggedMyAppProgDebug'.
  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzabt$1.class
```

As per the exception, my build had same file from two different modules. This happened because  different versions of Play services got included in the build. Since I needed to use firebase library, I had to update all my other modules to use version `10.0.1` of `Google Play Services`.